# Difference between multi-agent systems and distributed systems

Tags: agent-based-computing

What is the difference between multi-agent systems (MAS) and distributed systems, in the context of control with agents?

Answer (score -1):

**What is the difference between multi-agent systems (MAS) and distributed systems, in the context of control with agents?**

[Multi Agent System](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_system)
According to the book;  *Innovations,theories in  multi agent systems and applications, September,2015*

*It states that in multi agent system,agents have the ability to solve complex real world problems besides being autonomous and interlinked. thus exhibiting some intelligence*

Therefore,MAS falls under the umbrella of Distributed Artificial intelligence.e.g. Autonomous cars,SoftBots to mention but a few.

On the otherhand in Distributed systems,agents perform a specific task with the centralised agent taking control of the goal,that's achieved.e.g cellular network applications controlled by NOC,aircraft system that is controlled by Area Control Centres.

Therefore,Distributed systems,fall under the umbrella of  [Distributed Computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)